# Deploy ASP.NET Web API to Heroku

Tags: c#, heroku, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to `push` a ASP.NET Web API 2 application to heroku. Is this even possible? I have tried

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/jincod/dotnet-buildpack
```

and

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/friism/heroku-buildpack-mono/
```

and still getting a build fail.

### Error:

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting back from Heroku?

Comment: @arjabbar I updated my question with the error.

Answer (score 0):

This buildpack work with new asp.net 5 (dnx) apps and don't support old ASP.NET apps. You need buildpack with mono support. Try something from https://elements.heroku.com/search/buildpacks?q=mono

For new ASP.NET Core (https://www.asp.net/core) and .NET Core (https://www.microsoft.com/net/core) created new buildpack https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack and Demo application https://github.com/jincod/AspNet5DemoApp